# LDPC codes construction

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, random-matrices, coding-theory

According to Google Scholar original Gallager's article [Low-density parity-check codes](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1057683/) is cited more than 10000 times. It looks scary for non-experts.

I suspect that the number of algorithms for constructing good sparse matrices for [LDPC-codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-density_parity-check_code) is much less than 10000.  Is there any survey which contains description of such algorithms?

Basically I'm interested in explicit constructions based on number theory methods.

Comment: What's wrong with Margulis' construction which is based upon expanders? It provided some motivation to define expanders explicitly.

Comment: There is a new book coming out soon that might be what you're looking for: *LDPC Code Designs, Constructions, and Unification* by Li, Lin, Abdel-Ghaffar, Ryan, and Costello.

Comment: @Asaf Nothing is wrong. I'm just looking for survey.

Comment: @Timothy Chow I've found this book. It is well-written and contains a lot of useful information on LDPC codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ryan and Lin's *Channel Codes*](https://books.google.com/books?id=0gwqxBU_t-QC) has several chapters (computer-based, finite geometries, finite fields, combinatorial designs) devoted to various constructions of LDPC codes, as well as a chapter devoted to nonbinary codes that also details constructions for that case.

Comment: Thank you, very nice book. But for the first glance the book "LDPC Code Designs, Constructions, and Unification" from Timothy Chow's answer looks more fundamental.

Answer (score 3):

An overview of LDPC codes constructed using methods from combinatorial mathematics and finite geometry is given in [Low Density Parity Check Codes Based
on Finite Geometries: A Rediscovery and New Results](http://web.stanford.edu/group/cioffi/ee379b/class_reader/ucd1.pdf)

> In this paper, a geometric approach to the construction of LDPC codes
>   is presented. Four classes of LDPC codes have been constructed based
>   on the lines and points of the well known Euclidean and projective
>   geometries over finite fields. Their performance is compared with that
>   of randomly computer generated LDPC codes and irregular LDPC codes.